# TWN3 Mifare USB and Mifare Desfire

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I use TWN3 Mifare USB transceiver and a Mifare DESFire EV1 transponder.
I have a problem to get data from transponder.
(For serial communication I use Hercules SETUP utility 3.2.6.)

1. I open serial communication
2. put transponder on transciever
3. send 's' command in Hercules -> I will get UID of transponder
4. then I send `f0408000001` command to select application -> I will get `A0` response, why? For successful selection of an application I should get `00`

When I try to send `f020D02` to select file with ID 02 I always get `F` as answer (Error: general failure).

Structure of Mifare Desfire transponder is:

- Application (AID 000000)
- Application (AID 000001)

  - File 01 (file size 15 Byte)
  - File 02 (file size 4096 Byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code `A0` means *application not found*. So your MIFARE DESFire tag does not contain an application with that AID.

A typical error with MIFARE DESFire is the byte-order mismatches. So I would suggest that you verify that the AID is not `010000`.

If you have an NFC-enabled Android device, you could use an application like [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) to list the applications that are accessible on the card.

Comment: Do you know how read data from that? According to documentation I should use 'f051500000014' command to read 20 bytes from selected File but the transceiver return 'O' (it should mean 'operating mode failure').

The command mean:

f0515[Offset][BytesToRead],
Offset - 3 bytes in Hex,
BytesToRead - 1 byte

Comment: Did you select the file first? Is the file freely readable (without authentication and in plain communication mode)? Is the file a standard data file?

Comment: Yes, I selected the Application then I selected the File (it returns '00' it means successfully selected). Using NFC TagInfo app I found out that in 'Access conditions' for this File are Read, Write, Read&Write, Change Rights set on 'Free access'. Yes the File is 'Standart data file' and 'Access mode' is Plain text.